# Filter in WP child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter

I have this filter added in functions.php of my childtheme:

```
function tp_edit_ad_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['test'] = 'Something in title...';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-'.APP_POST_TYPE.'_columns', 'tp_edit_ad_columns', 11 );
```

Can anyone explain why it don't work? If this same function/filter is put in functions.php of the main theme it works.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: where and what does this filter have to do? and how does it differs to the original?

Comment: this filter add a column in the wordpress backend

Answer (score 0):

This is not a core filter.

So probably it is created in the parent theme.
For some reason it is turned down by your child theme.

Search the parent theme for `apply_filter` or `manage_edit` to find when this filter is applied.
From there you'll have to give moreinformation

Comment: Thank you janw for the answer, I've not yet found why it happens.

Comment: you couldn't find where this filter is applied? too bad :(